# Appended Div not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC 3 application and using razor syntax.

In this application I am giving commenting facility.

When user clicks on add comment button it get saved in DB and it also appends in current Div.

Please check image...

*This is the image before adding new comment...*

[image]

*This image is after adding new comment...*

[image]

Now, my problem is when user click on the newly added comment's Delete button I want to show msg - "Delete process start here..." but its now working...

Here is my code...

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model  IEnumerable<CRMEntities.Comment>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>



//Button which Saves currently added comment in DB as well display on screen...
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AddCommentButton').click(function () 

        {     

       // alert("clicked");
            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',
                url: '/Comment/SaveComments',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:
                { 

                 'comments' : $('#Comment').val(), 
                 'EType' : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EType)), 
                  'EId' : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.EId))

                },
                success: function (data) {

                    $("p.p12").append('<div style="background-color:#FAFAFA;">Recently Added... <br /><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Employee", new { id = "__id__" })'.replace('__id__', data.OwnerID) + '">' + data.OwnerName + '</a>'+ data.cmtDateTime +'<button type="button" id=' + data.Id  + ' class="deleteComment">Delete</button></span><br />' + data.msg + '</div>')


                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>




</head>
<body>

@{



     <div class="ParentBlock">


    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="OwnerClass" id="OwnerName">


         <span class="EmpName"> @Html.ActionLink(item.Owner.FullName, "Details", "EMployee", new { id = item.OwnerId }, new { @style = "color:#1A6690;" })</span>

           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentDateTime)

          <span class="EmpName"><button type="button" id = "@item.Id" class="deleteComment">Delete</button></span>



        <p class="CommentP">
           @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CommentText)
        </p>


        </div>


    }


     <p class="p12">

      </p>



</div>

      <p id="ClassPara" class="ShowComments" onclick="chkToggle()">Show All Comments</p>

}



   @Html.TextArea("Comment", "", 5, 80, "asdsd")


    <input type="button" value="Add Comment" id="AddCommentButton"/>                         
    <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearText()"/>                    

    <br />







</body>
</html>





<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


//   Working code - Deletes the comment from DB and removes hide the current Div
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".deleteComment").click(function ()
         {
            alert("Delete process start here...");

         });
    });



</script>
```

Comment: `$("body").on("click", ".deleteComment", function ()
     {
        alert("Delete process start here...");`
     }); I have tried this but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JQuery `[on][1]` instead of `click`;  the former will handle events dynamically as the document gets modified, while the latter wires up the event once, when you call it.

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteComment", function ()
     {
        alert("Delete process start here...");
     });
```